# Power BI: How to create a DAX formula that will also return the first non-zero value?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am currently doing a COVID-19 reports/dashboard through Power BI. I have this dax formula that will return the new cases for each day. However, the problem with this formula is that I am not able to return the value of the first case regardless if it's in the first row of a country or not. May I ask for suggestion on how to make this formula return the value of first case as well?

Datasource: [https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Here is the initial calculation I have made:

```
New_Cases = 
VAR Countries = ConfirmedCases[Country/Region]
VAR State = ConfirmedCases[Province/State]
VAR dates = ConfirmedCases[Date]
VAR PrevDay =
CALCULATE(
    MAX(ConfirmedCases[Cases]),
    FILTER('ConfirmedCases',
    ConfirmedCases[Country/Region]=Countries && ConfirmedCases[Province/State]=State && ConfirmedCases[Date]<dates))
RETURN
IF(PrevDay=0,0,
IF(PrevDay>[Cases],0,
IF(PrevDay>0,[Cases]-PrevDay)))
```

Here is the current output:
[DAX Formula that returns only the new cases each day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDC8I.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. BTW, this should be done in Power Query and not DAX.

```
New_Cases = 
VAR Countries = ConfirmedCases[Country/Region]
VAR State = ConfirmedCases[Province/State]
VAR dates = ConfirmedCases[Date]
VAR tbl =   FILTER('ConfirmedCases',
    ConfirmedCases[Country/Region]=Countries && ConfirmedCases[Province/State]=State && ConfirmedCases[Date]<dates)

VAR PrevDay =
CALCULATE(
    MAX(ConfirmedCases[Cases]),
     tbl)
RETURN

[Cases] - PrevDay
```

Comment: Thanks @David Bacci! Tried the formula above. However, it returns the same result.

Comment: Did you copy it exactly as written? I'll update the answer with a screenshot showing the outcome which I think is your desired behaviour.

Comment: Yes @David Bacci. Please refer to the shared image below of the output:

Comment: You need to share you whole .pbix. You screenshot shows the code working correctly i.e. Philippines starts with zero.

Comment: You can just update your question rather than adding an answer.

Comment: Thanks @David Bacci but I will need to return the value of the first case, regardless if its in the top of the row or not. First case for Philippines came at January 30 and it should return the value of 1 for New_Cases. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: I see the problem now. Let me update the code.

Comment: Try the new version and let me know.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for this! @David Bacci. The code shared above definitely meet the requirement! and it is also looks cleaner!